# I can't get monitor mode to work on Ubuntu MATE on an rpi3

Tags: ubuntu-mate, aircrack-ng, airmon-ng

Ok so these are the commands I used (from https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng and https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airodump-ng):

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UP6B.png)

I tried killing each of the processes using...

```
kill -9 4799
kill -9 4808
kill -9 4867
kill -9 4880
kill -9 4885
```

...and trying again afterwards, but still nothing.

I have made sure that the package is up to date and I have searched for solutions on the internet but to no avail.

Comment: By default the wifi chip on an rpi3 does not support monitor mode. But checkout this https://github.com/seemoo-lab/nexmon